# using struts-spring pluggin

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, struts

in my project they have mapping in this way, i found type parameter quite strange , goggled it , read about some struts spring plugin, can anyone give me a little idea why it is done in this way, or what is this...??

```
<action path="/loginAction"  
          type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy"  
          name="loginForm"  
          scope="request"  
          validate="false"  
          input="/showLoginAction.do">
```

Comment: sorry for the f word in the  post.. while i was trying to post it without F work, it said "it does't meet our quality standards". in frustration i typed that and it was posted :P

Comment: You better edit it then.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a spring struts plugin and means you have in another XML file a bean Called /loginAction that handles the URL .

This enables making struts actions spring béans and this way using spring ioc easily.

XML file is référenced some where in the struts-config.xml file or one of its dependencies.

Regards

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentaion, it will clear your all doubts. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/web/struts/DelegatingActionProxy.html